# Azure Devops pipeline build suddenly stopped working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-install, node-sass

Our Azure build pipeline started failing today. This was working fine with the same code a few days back. I'm struggling to find a reason. The build works fine in my local machine but doesn’t work on DevOps.

Below are some lines from the error log. Can anyone guide me to find the issue please?

Start of the error in the logs:

```
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1234486Z 6728 timing metavuln:packument:sass-loader Completed in 28ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1234976Z 6729 timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:sass-loader:sKa4m2v9CoUt2NE/HFdn2iHPGTVRUKpbo4oLNnOVBTLyHGQ/KmGqhFuwUlvkR/owQNQEXwZFOGQt5TNCCkoHWw== Completed in 5ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1235699Z 6730 timing metavuln:cache:put:security-advisory:sass-loader:0+Q0+uaac9NG7L1nbkGVbvFbaBvbLzENFqRpXWUE7U0t2jjSSjVZ79o6UtQRkcjQ/gcgS0kd8p2vAnNjva/3Eg== Completed in 15ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1236341Z 6731 timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:sass-loader:sKa4m2v9CoUt2NE/HFdn2iHPGTVRUKpbo4oLNnOVBTLyHGQ/KmGqhFuwUlvkR/owQNQEXwZFOGQt5TNCCkoHWw== Completed in 48ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1237034Z 6732 timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:imagemin-jpegtran:s0MaKyyWWIoVMQAlu89TduB0lW+w9ANmAjDodgTT4fcy4ki3FsHrWalCv/COtdz4o3adGXtGYSamW2jub7ta+Q== Completed in 1ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1237558Z 6733 info run node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1238006Z 6734 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/imagemin-jpegtran 5491ms (cache miss)
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1238399Z 6735 timing metavuln:packument:imagemin-jpegtran Completed in 5491ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1238952Z 6736 timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:imagemin-jpegtran:u6oOqPrIyXrFjQnhqewixjKDTSD2uoKmmWFnU4zRuXrk8rdHkm8zODnNe7xy3697n8Yy/cBLgdQBE6mFa/kxsg== Completed in 1ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1239443Z 6737 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 5296ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1239823Z 6738 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1240144Z 6739 timing command:install Completed in 77131ms
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1240444Z 6740 verbose stack Error: command failed
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1240974Z 6740 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1241517Z 6740 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1241956Z 6740 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1242405Z 6740 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1242817Z 6741 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.14.1
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1243073Z 6742 verbose cwd D:\a\1\s
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1243323Z 6743 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1243767Z 6744 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1244152Z 6745 verbose node v16.13.0
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1244424Z 6746 verbose npm  v8.1.0
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1244643Z 6747 error code 1
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1244930Z 6748 error path D:\a\1\s\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1245270Z 6749 error command failed
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1245577Z 6750 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1246161Z 6751 error Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\a\1\s\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1246648Z 6752 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
```

Last few lines of the log:

```
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1681219Z 6752 error gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.node-gyp\16.13.0
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1681621Z 6752 error gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1682050Z 6752 error gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1682559Z 6752 error gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1682993Z 6752 error gyp info spawn args [
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1683269Z 6752 error gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1683573Z 6752 error gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1683893Z 6752 error gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1684205Z 6752 error gyp info spawn args ]
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1684463Z 6752 error gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1684876Z 6752 error gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1685424Z 6752 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1685894Z 6752 error gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1686366Z 6752 error gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1686766Z 6752 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1687321Z 6752 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\a\\1\\s\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1687915Z 6752 error gyp ERR! cwd D:\a\1\s\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1688248Z 6752 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1688513Z 6752 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1688788Z 6752 error gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1689164Z 6752 error gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1689568Z 6752 error gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1689916Z 6752 error Build failed with error code: 7
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1690179Z 6753 verbose exit 1
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1690283Z 
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1720104Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
2021-12-04T09:08:08.1747833Z ##[section]Finishing: Npm
```

Below is the yaml file

```
name: 1.0.$(BuildID)-$(SourceBranchName)
trigger:
- release

variables:
  versionNumber: '1.0.$(BuildID)'
  mvcSolution: 'SVHA.MVC.Web.sln'
  
jobs:
  - job: "BuildStaging"
    variables:
      buildConfiguration: 'Staging'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    
    - task: Npm@1
      inputs:
        command: 'install'
        workingDir: './'

    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'npm run apps-build'
        workingDirectory: './'

    - task: Gulp@1
      inputs:
        gulpFile: 'gulpfile.js'
        targets: 'build'
        arguments: '--production'
        enableCodeCoverage: false
    
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    
        
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(mvcSolution)'    
 
    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(mvcSolution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Staging;DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False;_PackageTempDir="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\mvc"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: 'src\SVHA.Web\Config\staging'
        Contents: 'connectionStrings.config'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\mvc\Config'
        OverWrite: true
    
     
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\mvc'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\mvc.zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
    
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'staging'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: The error message is providing you details and a proposed solution. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `node-sass` and install `sass` instead.